# Em Python como passar o self entre 2 janelas usando módulos

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, pyqt, pyqt-5

Estou aprendendo Python, versão 3.7 com PyQT5 (Qt Designer)

Estou tentando definir o valor de uma label usando módulos, na window 1 ele chama a função e funciona, mas quando abro a window 2 e clico no botão ele aciona a função mas passa o self da janela atual (window 2) onde não tem label, gerando o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\template\config.py", line 18, in returnMain
    fun1(self)
  File "\modulos\functions.py", line 7, in fun1
    lbl = int(self.ui.lblTest.text())
AttributeError: 'Ui_window2' object has no attribute 'lblTest'
```

Preciso que ele use na função o self da window 1.

Repliquei o erro em arquivos pequenos, funciona até clicar no botão da segunda janela que da o erro descrito.

Segue a estrutura dos códigos no diretório:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue os arquivos.

**run.py (usado para startar o programa)**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
import sys

from template.main import MainScreen

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainScreen()
    main.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**gui/window1.py (janela principal)**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_window1(object):
    def setupUi(self, win1):
        win1.setObjectName("win1")
        win1.resize(297, 219)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(win1)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnConfig = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnConfig.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 150, 75, 23))
        self.btnConfig.setObjectName("btnConfig")
        self.lblTest = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lblTest.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 70, 47, 13))
        self.lblTest.setObjectName("lblTest")
        win1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(win1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(win1)

    def retranslateUi(self, win1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        win1.setWindowTitle(_translate("win1", "Window 1"))
        self.btnConfig.setText(_translate("win1", "Open config"))
        self.lblTest.setText(_translate("win1", "0"))
```

**gui/window2.py (janela de configurações)**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_window2(object):
    def setupUi(self, win2):
        win2.setObjectName("win2")
        win2.resize(222, 241)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(win2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnReturn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnReturn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 120, 75, 23))
        self.btnReturn.setObjectName("btnReturn")
        win2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(win2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(win2)

    def retranslateUi(self, win2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        win2.setWindowTitle(_translate("win2", "Window 2"))
        self.btnReturn.setText(_translate("win2", "Return Main"))
```

**modulos/functions.py (onde vão ficar as funções)**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from template import main

def fun1(self):
    lbl = int(self.ui.lblTest.text())
    lbl = (lbl+1)
    self.ui.lblTest.setText(str(lbl))
```

**template/config.py (onde vou tratar as configurações)**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from gui.window2 import *
from modulos.functions import fun1

class ConfigScreen(QMainWindow):
   
    def __init__(self,*args,**argsv):        
        super(ConfigScreen,self).__init__(*args,**argsv)
        self.ui = Ui_window2()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnReturn.clicked.connect(self.returnMain)

    def returnMain(self):
        fun1(self)
        self.close()
```

**template/main.py (módulo principal do programa)**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from gui.window1 import *
from template.config import ConfigScreen
from modulos.functions import fun1

class MainScreen(QMainWindow):
   
    def __init__(self,*args,**argsv):        
        super(MainScreen,self).__init__(*args,**argsv)
        self.ui = Ui_window1()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnConfig.clicked.connect(self.openConfig)

        fun1(self)

    def openConfig(self):        
        self.config = ConfigScreen()
        self.config.show()
```

**Lembre-se, oque é simples pra vc, pode ser muito difícil para outros.
Estou a 1 semana tentando resolver e não consigo, eu programava muito tempo atrás e estou tentando/precisando aprender algo novo**

Comment: Maurício, seja bem-vindo à nossa comunidade. Gostei muito da sua frase final e, aliás como diria meu ex diretor: "Tudo é muito fácil para quem não faz nada." Todo começo ou retomada de um estudo exige bastante esforço e espero que vc consiga atingir aí seus objetivos! Você elaborou muito bem a questão e tenho certeza que alguém te ajudará.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vc esta tentando alterar um atributo  que não existe na classe *ConfigScreen*; o atributo *lblTest* pertence ao seu ui na classe *MainScreen*. Quando vc chama a funcao *func1(self)* na classe *MainScreen* provavelmente funciona pois o self passado como parametro para a funcao é um referencia a classe *MainScreen* ou seja a propria  instancia da classe *MainScreen*; já na classe *ConfigScreen* quando vc chama a mesma *func1(self)* vc está passando a referencia da classe *ConfigScreen* e a funcao tenta alterar um atributo que não existe; para alterar o atributo *lblTest* vc precisa de uma referencia da classe principal para ter acesso a esse atributo;
então crie um parametro na inicializacao da classe *ConfigScreen* ex:

```
class ConfigScreen(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self,*args,**argsv, parent):        
    super(ConfigScreen,self).__init__(*args,**argsv, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.ui = Ui_window2()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.btnReturn.clicked.connect(self.returnMain)

def returnMain(self):
    fun1(self.parent)
    self.close()
```

o atributo self.parent pega a instancia da classe principal. E na classe *MainScreen* passe  o self na instanciacao da classe *ConfigScreen* ex:

```
def openConfig(self):        
    self.config = ConfigScreen(self) # parent recebe o self como valor
    self.config.show()
```

Comment: Obrigado @karllos, consegui resolver com sua resposta, teve um pequeno detalhe que gerou outro erro mas consegui resolver e compartilhei como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

o karlloss está certo, em `returnMain` não é necessário passar o objeto para `func1`.

Talvez a confusão esteja no entendimento do parâmetro `self`, ele funciona muito parecido com o `this` em outras linguagens como Java ou JavaScript. É um parâmetro da classe a qual ele pertence e só existe dentro dessa classe. Se quiser passar as propriedades de uma classe para outra use o próprio objeto instanciado e não o self.

Perceba que aqui:

```
def fun1(self):
    lbl = int(self.ui.lblTest.text())
    lbl = (lbl+1)
    self.ui.lblTest.setText(str(lbl))
```

O argumento `self` poder, por exemplo, ter outro nome, já que ele não faz parte de nenhuma classe.

Continue os estudos, com a prática alguns conceitos vão começar a fazer mais sentido :)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver com a resposta do karlloss.

A principio tinha gerado um erro:

```
    def __init__(self,*args,**argsv, parent):
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Pesquisando um pouco descobri que o parent deve vir antes dos outros argumentos:

```
class ConfigScreen(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **argsv):        
        super(ConfigScreen,self).__init__(parent, *args,**argsv)
        self.parent = parent
        self.ui = Ui_window2()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnReturn.clicked.connect(self.returnMain)

    def returnMain(self):
        fun1(self.parent)
        self.close()
```

Após essa pequena correção tudo funcionou perfeitamente.

Muito obrigado aos envolvidos.